# Form Recogniser API call - error code 202-accepted

Tags: c#, function, azure-form-recognizer

I used the labelled tool to train my model and got the model ID. Then I tried to make an API call (https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm) and use this model ID to analyse form but got the error code 202. My resource (Form Recognizer cognitive service) is in West Europe. Any idea what might be wrong with my request? If I click on the Operation-location from the response, then I see the error code 401.

Is there anywhere I can find a source code for a blob triggered azure function so I can use the model ID I have created using the labelling tool? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 202 response is not an error code, instead it means that your first POST API call was successful. The next step would be to make a GET call (https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/GetAnalyzeFormResult) using the Operation-Location from your response and the same subscription key you used before.